# URLFetchService with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I used to have this code working with my Tomcat server:

```
HttpRequestBase targetRequest = ...;
HttpResponse targetResponse = httpclient.execute(targetRequest);
HttpEntity entity = targetResponse.getEntity();
```

However when I migrated with Google App Engine, I can' use this code anymore. So I read a bit and found that I need to use another code to achieve this.

So I have this code:

```
 URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
 HTTPResponse targetRespose = fetcher.fetch(targetRequest); // Error
 HttpEntity entity = targetResponse.getEntity();
```

However its obvious that there's an error with the `fetcher.fetch` code.

All I need to accomplish to to have the same HttpEntity using App Engine approach. Any way to work this out?

Comment: What is the error? Any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`org.apache.http.HttpRequest`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) and [`com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPRequest) are two totally different classes from two different libraries, so you can not just exchange one for the other.

If you'd like to use Apache HttpClient on GAE, it can be done with some workarounds: see [here](http://esxx.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html) and [here](http://peterkenji.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-apache-httpclient-4-with-google.html).

Comment: I will try to do the workaround, however is it something that App engine might patch and not work in the future? This is why I am trying to migrate as much as possible to the App Engine way, anyway I will try that workaround...

Comment: Then use just `URLFetchService` and remove all HttpClient classes.

Comment: Ok, so what is the closest match to a HttpEntity with App engine, if none what is the alternative so I can build the HttpEntity?

Comment: Unfortunately `HTTPResponse.getContent()` is the only way to get content. There is no higher-level API to parse/transform http response body (decoding, multipart, etc..)